# Coordinator pattern doesn't work inside UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, coordinator-pattern

I have 2 buttons inside a View and I can't understand why the Coordinator Pattern does not work for navigation with ViewControllers, only the print inside the button works, but not the delegate for navigation.

Coordinator.swift

import UIKit

```
protocol Coordinator {
var childCoordinators: [Coordinator] {get set}
init(navigationController: UINavigationController)
func start() 
}
```

MainCoordinator.swift

```
    import UIKit
    
    class MainCoordinator: Coordinator {
        
        var childCoordinators: [Coordinator] = []
        
        unowned var navigationController: UINavigationController
        
        required init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
            self.navigationController = navigationController
        }
        
        func start() {
         let vc: MonitoringViewController = MonitoringViewController()
            vc.delegate = self
            
            self.navigationController.viewControllers = [vc]
        }
        
    }

extension MainCoordinator: NavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    // go to MonitoringViewController
    func navigateToMonitoringViewController() {
        let monitoringViewController: MonitoringViewController = MonitoringViewController()
        monitoringViewController.delegate = self
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(monitoringViewController, animated: false)
    }
    
    // go to AlertViewController
    func navigateToAlertViewController() {
        let alertViewController: AlertViewController = AlertViewController()
        alertViewController.delegate = self
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(alertViewController, animated: false)
    }

}
```

MonitoringViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class MonitoringViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var CustomNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

}
```

CustomNavigationBar.swift

```
import UIKit

public protocol NavigationControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func navigateToMonitoringViewController()
    func navigateToAlertViewController()
}

final class CustomNavigationBar: UIView {
    
    public weak var delegate: NavigationControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonNavBar1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.navigateToMonitoringViewController()
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonNavBar2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.navigateToAlertViewController()
        print("PRINT ALERT")
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate on the `CustomNavigationBar`?

Comment: Andrew, i have already put the delegates, do I have to put others?

Comment: Coordinators are a huge anti-pattern in iOS. I'd recommend avoiding them as much as possible. Even Saroush Khan-Lou the guy who wrote the blog that went viral never used them. The company he was working for at the time got into a big mess with them and removed them before they ever shipped an app using it.

Comment: @Fogmeister Do you have any reference? I'm interested in this feedback (even if I don't personally use this pattern)

Comment: @Larme only a conversation I had with someone who worked there. No reference though. Sorry. But, when you look at what it is asking people to do. You're essentially mirroring (sort of) your entire UIViewController stack with another stack of Coordinators. Except, where the UIViewController stack is managed by UIKit, you get no management of the Coordinator stack at all. So you have to put in work to sync up the management of the coordinator stack etc... There is one place that benefits from a coordinator pattern and thats when you don't know the flow of the feature because it's dynamic.

Comment: @Larme a longer answer... https://oliverfoggin.com/2022/01/22/we-need-to-talk-about-the-coordinator-pattern/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomNavigationBar delegate property was not set. Set it to MonitoringViewController instance in viewDidLoad method and add support for NavigationControllerDelegate members in MonitoringViewController instance.

Property names should be written in Lower Camel Case notation, you should change:

```
@IBOutlet weak var CustomNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar!
```

to

```
@IBOutlet weak var customNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar!
```

---

1. Solution Monitor View Controller is middle man between customNavigationBar and can react to delegate actions and create side effects

---

```
class MonitoringViewController: UIViewController, NavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var customNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar!
    weak var delegate: NavigationControllerDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customNavigationBar.delegate = self
    }

    func navigateToMonitoringViewController() {
      delegate?.navigateToMonitoringViewController()
    }

    func navigateToAlertViewController() {
      delegate?.navigateToAlertViewController()
    }

}
```

2. Solution Monitor View Controller is middle man between customNavigationBar but can't react to interactions between customNavigationBar and coordinator

---

```
class MonitoringViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar!
    weak var delegate: NavigationControllerDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customNavigationBar.delegate = delegate
    }

}
```

3. The same solution as second one but this time MonitoringViewController has computed delegate which removes a need to set relation between coordinator and customNavigationBar in 'viewDidLoad' method

---

```
class MonitoringViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar!
    var delegate: NavigationControllerDelegate? {
      get { customNavigationBar.delegate }
      set { customNavigationBar.delegate = newValue }
    }
}
```